# jersey bean validation on multipart/form-data content type in post method in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

Post Model class
   public class Post implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7381056071294028885L;
private int id;
@NotNull
private int userId;
private List<CommentDetail> commentDetails;
@NotNull
private int totalComment;
@NotNull
private int favLikes;
@NotNull
private int unFavLikes;
private List<MediaList> mediaList;
@NotNull
private int postStatus;
private Date createdDate;
private Date modifiedDate;
@NotNull
private String title;
@NotNull
private String postSectionId;
@NotNull
private int isMediaContain;
private String pageId;
@NotNull
private int isChannelPost;
@NotNull
private int postType;
@NotNull
private String postContent;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public List<CommentDetail> getCommentDetails() {
    return commentDetails;
}

public void setCommentDetails(List<CommentDetail> commentDetails) {
    this.commentDetails = commentDetails;
}

public int getTotalComment() {
    return totalComment;
}

public void setTotalComment(int totalComment) {
    this.totalComment = totalComment;
}

public int getFavLikes() {
    return favLikes;
}

public void setFavLikes(int favLikes) {
    this.favLikes = favLikes;
}

public int getUnFavLikes() {
    return unFavLikes;
}

public void setUnFavLikes(int unFavLikes) {
    this.unFavLikes = unFavLikes;
}

public List<MediaList> getMediaList() {
    return mediaList;
}

public void setMediaList(List<MediaList> mediaList) {
    this.mediaList = mediaList;
}

public int getPostStatus() {
    return postStatus;
}

public void setPostStatus(int postStatus) {
    this.postStatus = postStatus;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Date getModifiedDate() {
    return modifiedDate;
}

public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPostSectionId() {
    return postSectionId;
}

public void setPostSectionId(String postSectionId) {
    this.postSectionId = postSectionId;
}

public int getIsMediaContain() {
    return isMediaContain;
}

public void setIsMediaContain(int isMediaContain) {
    this.isMediaContain = isMediaContain;
}

public String getPageId() {
    return pageId;
}

public void setPageId(String pageId) {
    this.pageId = pageId;
}

public int getIsChannelPost() {
    return isChannelPost;
}

public void setIsChannelPost(int isChannelPost) {
    this.isChannelPost = isChannelPost;
}

public int getPostType() {
    return postType;
}

public void setPostType(int postType) {
    this.postType = postType;
}

public String getPostContent() {
    return postContent;
}

public void setPostContent(String postContent) {
    this.postContent = postContent;
}




@POST
@Path("/post")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addPostWithMedia(final FormDataMultiPart multiPart,final @Valid Post post) {
    List<FormDataBodyPart> bodyParts = multiPart.getFields("files");
    return contentService.savePost(post, bodyParts);
}
```

The error is returned:

> Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.\n[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.storyshell.controller.FeedController.addPostWithMedia(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart,com.storyshell.model.Post) at index 1.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.storyshell.controller.FeedController, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1408a587]}, handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.storyshell.controller.FeedController.addPostWithMedia(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart,com.storyshell.model.Post), parameters=[Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.storyshell.model.Post, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] The (sub)resource method addPost in com.storyshell.controller.FeedController contains empty path annotation.; source='public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.storyshell.controller.FeedController.addPost(com.storyshell.model.Post)']"

Comment: Format the error code properly

Comment: Are you trying to inject something into the Post parameter? What is Post? Your issue is that jersey does not know what on eary a "Post" is, so when trying to inject it it tries to resolve the type, but can't work out what to do with it. You can use Post to inject form parameters (by using @BeanParam) but that makes no sense becaue you also inject the formparams directly, so it looks like a) your endpoint is a bit weird and b) you are missing an injection resolver for jersey to create your Post

Comment: Post is model class.

Comment: Update your post with your model class and explain how the model class is meant to be created by jersey for you?

Comment: well, that was unfortunate. I meant: Update your StackOverflow post above and add the model class Post so we can see what you are trying to inject as then we'll be able to let you know why it does not work :)